# read jSON response

Tags: java, android, django, json

I am trying to read a json response from my python based backend. I am using this code for accessing the information.

**URL for first call**

```
public static final String JSON_RESPONSE_STRING="http://192.168.2.5:8000/mobile/";
```

**URL forsecond call**

```
public static final String PICKUP_DETAILS="http://192.168.2.5:8000/mobile/shippments/";
```

**common method using**

```
public static String GetJSONResponse(String stringUrl) throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder response  = new StringBuilder();

        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),8192);
            String strLine = null;
            while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response.append(strLine);
            }
            input.close();
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
```

**django url patterns**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('mobile_api.views',
                       url(r'^$','login_authenticate'),
                       url(r'^shippments/(?P<id>\w+)','pickup_details'),
                       url(r'^report/post/','pickup_report')
                       )
```

I am using this method twice in my code. For the first time this code is working absolutely fine and parsing the json response .

When I am using this method at other place I am call it

```
pick_up_id=getIntent().getStringExtra("pickup_id");
        String stringUrl=Constants.PICKUP_DETAILS+"555";
        String response = null;
        try {
            response = PickupList.GetJSONResponse(stringUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //String response=GetPickUpDetails(pick_up_id);
        System.out.println("second call response"+response);
```

and getting this response

```
03-22 12:19:37.979: I/System.out(20703): second call response<!doctype html>  <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->  <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->  <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->  <head>    <meta charset="utf-8">    <title>ECOM</title>            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1" >    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">            <meta name="description" content="">    <meta name="author" content="">        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />            <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.domain.com/images/logo.png"/>    <meta property="og:title" content="-- description here --"/>    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domain.com"/>            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/assets/img/favicon.ico" />    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/static/assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png">    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/static/assets/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/static/assets/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/styles.css" />                    <script src="/static/assets/js/libs/modernizr.custom.60077.js"></script>          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/popup.css" />           <script src="/static/assets/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>           <script src="/static/assets/authentication/js/popup.js"></script>    </head><body><div id="backgroundPopup"></div>      <div class="header" style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px;">       <img src="/static/assets/img/Ecomlogo.png"/>  </div>   <div class="container-fluid" roll="main" id="main">    <div class="span6"><a href="/track_me/scan_open/1/" class="forgotpass pull-right">Track Shipment</a>      <div class="login">        <div class="title">          Login                  </div>                <div class="content-login">          <form action="." method="POST">          <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='p0SPV6QzpX2nP2p588V5lDU9s9LLWZDO' /></div>              <input type= "text" name ="username" placeholder="Username" class="user-name"/>            <input type= "Password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>            <input type="submit" class="button-login"/>            <a href="#" class="forgotpass pull-right" id="forgotpass">Forgot Your Password?</a>          </form>        </div>      </div>    </div>    <div class="span6">      <div class="login">        <div class="title">          Ecom Express News                  </div>        <div class="content-login">                  </div>      </div>    </div>  </div>       <!-- modal -->  <div class="modal hide modal-add-revlet" id="add-revlet">    <div class="modal-header">      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>      <h3>Record</h3>    </div>    <div class="modal-body">          </div>  </div><!--modal end-->   <div id="popupContact">             <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>    </div>        <!-- uncomment pre-deloy -->  <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>  <!-- bootstrap -->  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>  <script src="/static/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
```

**P.S** Also, if there is any problem with the code then why is it working for first call.
**NOTE 1** Both the response are json objects I have verified several times.my backend is **dJango**. On hitting the url on browser I am getting the correct response in .json format

Comment: plz share Constants.PICKUP_DETAILS value

Comment: as in output currently server returning full html of Login Page. just make sure u are using right url for getting json

Comment: What url are you passing in the first time? As @ρяσѕρєяK points out, you could be using a wrong url.

Comment: You seem to be appending `555` to your url. Is that intended? Is that the same thing you do for the first call too?

Comment: @all question has been modified

Comment: have you disabled django's csrf check for your url?

Comment: @KorniltsevAnatoly u mean `@csrf_exempt` ? I am using this in views.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for `csrf_exempt` or proper permission for access to the url from app