# POST request for dJango from android app

Tags: java, android, django

I have tried these approaches with no success

- Approach 1
  [JSON Response from Django in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497833/json-response-from-django-in-android)
- Approach 2
  [read jSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564452/read-json-response)

to send a POST request from android app tp python based web service, but I am unable to get the required results. Please share a good tutorial snippet for the same or any modifications so that either of my code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving a quick guess here, but POST looks more like a **w3c.org "MIME"** request for mail.
You send headers on separate lines(CRLF) add onto a line in that a "string" in condition similar to a get request by appearence of that string is URL encoded unlike the headers, just like taken from an HTML form and similar to JSON notation.

So see if android imports `java.net.URLConnection` or has its own class for `java.net.URLConnection` .

The server side script language Python acts similar to most new web server side script languages and should have server environment variables that can be "named" with the form field name to retrieve is from the server platform script thread.
e.g. PHP   `$_POST{"emailfield"}`
where

```
<input type="text" name="emailfield" id="emailfield" value="" />
```